# Is there any way to implement nested grids using jquery or any open source libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, kendo-grid

Currently the nested grids are implemented using Telerik Kendo in ASP. NET MVC application. But I need to implement without using Kendo grids.

Tried using free version of datatables. But not working as expected. Open to use any free versions(Angular is excluded)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Asking the community to "_recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_" is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You may have more success if you can ask a specific question about a specific problem you are facing. For example, when you mention one attempt is "_not working as expected_", you can ask a new question providing a full [mre] for that. You can also take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance.